# Import data from CA Clarity into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, clarity

I am trying to download resource names and hours for a specific project from CA Clarity PPM using Excel. I need the macro to access clarity PPM(www.abcd.hosting.ca.com) using username and password and download resource details if login is correct. Any suggestions how this can be done using VBA?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For every NSQL query that is created in Clarity a web service is also created.  You could write something in VBA to authenticate to the web service and pull the information and then parse it appropriately.

Here is an example of VBA calling a web service:

http://www.webcontinuum.net/ws_4.aspx

Here is a link to get you started on integrations:

https://communities.ca.com/web/ca-clarity-global-user-community/message-board/-/message_boards/message/2295385

See the question "Q : Web Services Interface (WSDL)"

Answer (score 0):

If this can help other... I started the same work here but I am struggling myself to get information from Clarity ppm using their webservices...

[Export Project List from Clarity PPM To Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699384/export-project-list-from-clarity-ppm-to-excel)

Also, I Found this thread that provides great VBA Example :
https://communities.ca.com/thread/117927268